# Laravel Query 4 table

Tags: laravel, database

I list my orders and I list the total number of these orders. Can you help me how to specify the order color I want?

controller code;

```
$orders = Order::select('order.*', 'order_piece.*', DB::raw('SUM(order_piece.piece) As piece'))
        ->Join('order_piece', 'order_piece.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
        ->where('order.collection_id', $request->model_id)
        ->groupBy('order_piece.order_id')
        ->get();
```

database design;[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep joining to the other tables down to the color, so that you can add a where filter on the `color.name`? (well, I assume that the color's name is the desired filter in this example)

```
$orders = Order::select('order.*', 'order_piece.*', DB::raw('SUM(order_piece.piece) As piece'))
    ->join('order_piece', 'order_piece.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
    ->join('collection_color_size_barcode', 'collection_color_size_barcode.id', '=', 'order_piece.collection_color_size_barcode_id')
    ->join('collection_color', 'collection_color.id', '=', 'collection_color_size_barcode.collection_color_id')
    ->join('color', 'color.id', '=', 'collection_color.color_id')
    ->where('order.collection_id', $request->model_id)
    ->where('color.name', 'red') // not sure what variable you need here?
    ->groupBy('order_piece.order_id')
    ->get();
```